# Plus Concatenation String operator in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, operators, string-concatenation, console.log

I came across the scenario trying with different operating concatenations. I am wondering how this condition was working for the 2nd statement.

1. `console.log("10"+9); // 109`
2. `Console.log("10"-9); //1`

Can Someone tell me what's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+` is used for both string concatenation and addition. If either operand is a string, concatenation is used. `-` is only used for subtraction, both operants are always coerced to numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The plus sign is both an Arithmetic operator and the String Concatenation operator. The concatenation has precedence.